# How to parse numbers from excel sheet using OpenXML C#

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, openxml, openxml-sdk

My main goal is to parse emails from a spreadsheet. What I need is to detect if a cell is containing anything other than an Email (wrong format, boolean, number...) to add this cell to an array (assume invalids)

What I did:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);

            Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

            worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)(workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id));

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
                {
                    cell = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference == String.Format("A{0}", reader.GetText())).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (cell != null && cell.InnerText.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var value = cell.InnerText;

                        if (cell.DataType != null)
                        {
                            var stringTable = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();

                            if (cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                            {
                                value = stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                                values.Add(value);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // add the invalid to the array
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            spreadsheetDocument.Close();
        }
```

Forget about email validation, **my problem is that I want to extract non-string values.** I have tried lots of things but the code is not reaching the **else** where it suppose to extract the numbers while there is booleans and numbers in the spreadsheet. Where is the problem? How to extract those non-string values?

Comment: Honestly use EEPlus or something similar, someone has done the hardwork for you. It's straightforward to use and takes the hassle out of what you are attempting to do. I have used EEPlus a number of times, it takes out the grunt work. You can use Linq to query the worksheet. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312166/find-and-replace-all-string-using-epplus to get an idea.

Comment: @Richard does it work on linux? Im deploying on an ubuntu machine

Comment: There is Epplus.Core, EPPlus.Core -Version 1.5.4. Just checked on Github it should: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/224

Comment: thank you! much appreciated

Comment: It might help to look at the internal Excel Open XML, using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. Perhaps all the content has been stored as a "Shared String" so that you'd need to check whether what's coming from there can be converted to a number, or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used EPPLUS Core which is a good wrapper for OpenXML